# How much memory is allocated for static primitive type and static reference type in Java

Tags: java, memory

I have two different class with static variables. One class with static reference type variables and another class with static primitive type variables. When i calculated the size of the each static variables using Instrumentation.getObjectSize() method it returns the same size. But from my understanding, class object has header section and padding section additional to its global variables so this reference type is always should be great in memory while compared to primitive type. Please find my code below:

**ObjectSizeFetcher.java**

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

**DaysOfWeek1.java**

```
public class DaysOfWeek1 {
    public static final DaysOfWeek1 Sunday = new DaysOfWeek1(1);
    public static final DaysOfWeek1 Monday = new DaysOfWeek1(2);
    public static final DaysOfWeek1 Tuesday = new DaysOfWeek1(4);
    public static final DaysOfWeek1 Wednesday = new DaysOfWeek1(8);
    public static final DaysOfWeek1 Thursday = new DaysOfWeek1(16);
    public static final DaysOfWeek1 Friday = new DaysOfWeek1(32);
    public static final DaysOfWeek1 Saturday = new DaysOfWeek1(64);

    private int intValue;

    private DaysOfWeek(int value) {
        intValue = value;
    }
}
```

**DaysOfWeek2.java**

```
public final class DaysOfWeek2 {
    public static final int Sunday = (1);
    public static final int Monday = (2);
    public static final int Tuesday = (4);
    public static final int Wednesday = (8);
    public static final int Thursday = (16);
    public static final int Friday = (32);
    public static final int Saturday = (64);

}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int i=10;
        long value = ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(DaysOfWeek1.Friday);
        System.out.println(value);// provide 16 bytes

        long value1 = ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(DaysOfWeek2.Sunday);
        System.out.println(value1);// provide 16 bytes

        long value2 = ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(i);
        System.out.println(value2);// provide 16 bytes
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me how JVM allocates memory for the above scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sarath

Comment: What's up with the parentheses in `Sunday = (1);`?

Answer (score 0):

`getObjectSize()` is meant to give an approximation of the size of *objects* of the specified type. They aren't affected by static fields, because static fields exist on a per-*type* basis rather than a per-*object* basis.

Add as many static fields as you like, and I wouldn't expect `getObjectSize` to change.

Comment: Then in my case the following should be the result.

Case 1: DaysOfWeek1.Friday
8 bytes for header
4 bytes for int field
4 bytes for padding,

So totally 16 bytes.

Case 2: DaysOfWeek2.Sunday

It is an integer static and so its size should be 4 bytes.

Case 3: i

It is local integer variable and is size should be 4 bytes.

Am I correct in the above cases?

Comment: @sarathkumar: Right, and it *does* print 16. So what's confusing?

Comment: For the last two cases it prints the wrong value right?

Comment: @sarathkumar: It's very frustrating to try to reply to a comment which is edited multiple times. No, any time that you're passing an `int` value, it's being boxed to `Integer`. So you're finding the size of an `Integer` object, which will be 8 bytes for the header, 4 bytes for the int field, and 4 bytes for padding, just like `DaysOfWeek1`.

Comment: Since it is my first time to using this windows, so when Im press enter added my comment. Sorry. Thanks for your answer.